# How to connect with different tables depending on parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model Board and BoardController where i can find all boards of my project. 
All records have filled "board_layout" column with enum.

Now i have show method in BoardController and i want to load there different data from different table depending on board_layout column value.

I could do it like this:

```
def show
  @board = Board.find(params[:id])
  if @board.board_layout == 1
    @tasks = Car.where(board_id: @board.id)
  elsif @board.board_layout == 2
    @tasks = Truck.where(board_id: @board.id)
  end
end
```

But it's not elegant + it is not DRY (i need to use some sort of if statement anytime when i want to do something with those 2 tables).

So i have tried to create Concern and create case statement inside, now it looks like:

```
def show
  @board = Board.find(params[:id])
  @tasks = get_class_name(@board.board_layout).where(board_id: @board.id)
end

# inside my concern
def get_class_name(scope)
  case scope
  when 1
    Car
  when 2
    Truck
  end
end
```

My Question:
Is there better way to do it? Is my solution safe and clear? 
What is the best solution to resolve problem like this?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Change board_layout by string like "Car" or "Truck" and make this:

`@tasks = @board.board_layout.safe_constantize.where(board_id: @board.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can abstract that out into a class, so you can define multiple layout and their correspondent classes, like:

```
class LayoutClassGetter
  CLASS_BY_LAYOUT = { '1' => Car, '2' => Truck }.freeze

  def initialize(layout_number)
    @layout_number = layout_number
  end

  def layout_class
   CLASS_BY_LAYOUT[@layout_number]
  end

  def self.layout_class(layout_number)
    new(layout_number).layout
  end
end
```

And then use it:

```
def show
  @board = Board.find(params[:id])
  @tasks = layout_class(@board.board_layout).where(board_id: @board.id)
end

def layout_class(scope)
  LayoutClassGetter.layout_class(scope)
end
```

Comment: Where would you suggest to place this class file in?